# Can't figure out how to enter BIOS on a Lenovo Z510

Tags: boot, bios, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Z510 Ideapad. I find I can’t enter bios to change settings, when I turn on my laptop, I press <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F1</kbd> to enter BIOs, but have no luck

I have also been trying to run system from Lenovo OneKey Recovery (Novo button) and the BIOs menu item will appear but when I click on it a black screen will appear and it doesn’t do anything. I even updated the BIOs with a download from Lenovo’s site but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: F10, Del ?  (F12 is often the boot selection menu)

Comment: @Hannu .. I have tried all of this keys. I already entered into bios. But recently I try all of this ways but have no luck!

Answer (score 4):

### How do I enter the BIOS on a Lenovo Z510?

> To  start the BIOS setup utility:
>
> 1. Shut down the computer.
> 2. Press the "Novo" button and then select "BIOS Setup".
>
> [image]

---

#### When I click on BIOS Setup a black screen will appear and it doesn't do anything

Try a System Restore.

> You can choose to restore the system partition to its original status
>   or to a previously created back-up point. To restore the system
>   partition:
>
> 1. Press the Novo button, then click OneKey Recovery to start the Lenovo OneKey Recovery System.
> 2. Click System Recovery. The computer will restart to the recovery environment.
> 3. Follow the on-screen instructions to restore the system partition to its original status or to a previously created back-up point.

Source [Lenovo Z410/Z510/Z510 Touch User Guide](http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/z510_ug_en.pdf)